# How to print list's specific index element?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a `list`  :

```
list1 = [['1', 'jay', '1000'],
         ['2', 'vijay', '5000'],
         ['3', 'roft', '1500'],
         ['2', 'mickey', '4700']]
```

I want to print only specific element that is salary in above example(1000,5000,1500,4700).

How can i print it, so i can do operation on it ?

Comment: Maybe using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier this question is in python, not php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using a multi-dimensional list(array), first identify the list that contains the element, followed by the desired element's index within the list.

Let n be the index of the list,

i be the index of the element.

mDList[n][i]

```
list1 = [['1', 'jay', '1000'],
         ['2', 'vijay', '5000'],
         ['3', 'roft', '1500'],
         ['2', 'mickey', '4700']]

# Returns ['1', 'jay', '1000']
print(list1[0])

# Returns 1000
print(list1[0][2])

# Returns index 2 in element n
for element in list1:
    print(element[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list-comprehension:

```
list1 = [['1', 'jay', '1000'], ['2', 'vijay', '5000'],['3', 'roft', '1500'], ['2', 'mickey', '4700']]

print([x[2] for x in list1])
# ['1000', '5000', '1500', '4700']
```

Or:

```
print([z for _, _, z in list1])
# ['1000', '5000', '1500', '4700']
```

Answer (score 0):

zip:

```
list1 = [['1', 'jay', '1000'], ['2', 'vijay', '5000'],[['3', 'roft', '1500'], ['2', 'mickey', '4700']]]
print(list(zip(*list1))[2])
```